# How to get last inserted id from table MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am running 1 script in php for that I need last inserted id in subscription table. By using that id I want to make notification note for that subscription.

I used:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM subscription
```

I am getting 0 instead of real last inserted value.

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is *connection specific*. Make sure you're not closing the connection and opening a new one between queries, or attempting to call this function from a separate script.

Answer (score 10):

If you use `php` to connect to `mysql` you can use `mysql_insert_id()` to point to last inserted id.

Like this :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (1, 2, 3, 'blah')");
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

See this : [mysql_insert_id()](http://au.php.net/mysql_insert_id)

Answer (score 5):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the last id from a previous insert statement.  If you want the most recently inserted record and are using Auto Increment Prime keys, you can use the code below:

```
SELECT MAX( id ) FROM subscription;
```

If you need to know what the **NEXT** id will be, you can get this from INFORMATION_SCHEMA

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'test'
```

[mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id)

Comment: +1 but `MAX(id)` isn't necessarily close to the *next* value the auto-increment will generate, because someone could have deleted some rows from the end of the table.

Comment: @BillKarwin The OP didn't ask for what the *Next* id will be.

Comment: Yes, point taken, but it's still possible (though rare) that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` could return a value higher than `MAX(id)` if the row you just inserted is deleted.

Comment: Also `MAX(id)` could return a value greater than the one you just inserted, if other sessions are also inserting their own rows.

Answer (score 3):

This question has already been answered many times: [MySQL: LAST_INSERT_ID() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880267/mysql-last-insert-id-returns-0)

You are using that function out of context. It will only work if you inserted a row immediately prior thusly:

```
INSERT INTO 'subscription' (name) VALUES ('John Smith');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM subscription
```

You can however select the row with the highest id, which logically would be the most recently added...

```
SELECT MAX( id ) FROM subscription;
```

**The standard approach however is to simply call `mysqli_insert_id`** or `mysql_insert_id` (depending on whether you are using the mysqli or mysql PHP library. I should add that the mysql library is very inadvisable to use since it is almost completely deprecated). Here's what the whole thing would ideally look like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO 'subscription' (name) VALUES ('John Smith');");
printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
//Output is something like: New Record has id 999
```

*If however you didn't insert a subscription in the same script as collecting the most recent row ID, use the 'select max' approach. This seems unlikely given that you mentioned '1 script'*

*Also, if your ID's are non-consecutive, or you do not have an ID field, or you have row ID's higher than the one you just added you should probably consider a 'date_added' column to determine which one was really the latest. These scenarios are rather unlikely however.*

Answer (score 3):

this is the better approach 2 and 3 works but MAX(id) take more time to execute.

1. `SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbName' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tableName';`
2. `SELECT tableName.id  FROM tableName ORDER BY tableName.id DESC LIMIT 0,1;`
3. `SELECT MAX( id ) FROM tableName;`

Comment: This solution must be used with care, since two (or more) concurrent  transactions might get the same value

Answer (score 1):

This will always give you the maximum id, which says the biggest number is the last inserted one

```
 SELECT MAX(id) as MaximumID FROM subscription;
```

Comment: Yes, it will be the biggest value, but if other sessions are also inserting, then `MAX(id)` won't necessarily return the last value generated by *your* session.

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: Also, if you ignore `auto_increment` by manually inserting value `10` when the largest id is already `100`, your approach wil fail as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$last_id=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `table_name` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 1" );
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($last_id);
echo $row['id'];
```

Replace `id` by your id field name in database and `table_name` by your table name.