# Get the last inserted system id of a certain table before doing any query pdo php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

From [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) tutorial i found a way to get the last inserted id of a specific table (with pdo).In the example

```
$result = $db->exec("INSERT INTO table(firstname, lastname) VAULES('John', 'Doe')");
$insertId = $db->lastInsertId();
```

he made a query before getting the id i would to make something like this but i want to get the id oft he last inserted entry first before doing any query.`How should i tell the code that it should check the last inserted id from this table`. Any idea is appreciated.

`Update`

I want to get the `last inserted id` of a **specific table** not only the last inserted id of the database

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get last inserted id from table mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891875/how-to-get-last-inserted-id-from-table-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

its return last inserted id before any query run.

```
select * from yourtable order by id desc limit 0,1
```

Comment: how can i get the id after that query run `lastinsertedid()` ?

Comment: $stmt = $db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$lastId = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$lastId = $lastId[0];

Comment: can i add a where clause right after `lastinsertedid` for example `where location = asia` something like this?also i want to select a specific table for this