# How to get last auto increment id from a table in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php

I have a table called Meeting with ID auto increment

I want select query to get last auto increment id. However, I used MAX(ID) but there is an issue which is if I delete last record will not work.

Comment: whats about this SELECT your_id FROM your_table ORDER BY your_id DESC LIMIT 1 ?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem-what do you want the auto increment ID for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get last inserted id from table MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891875/how-to-get-last-inserted-id-from-table-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this query:

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db_name'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'your_table_name'
```